# How do I setup health notifications for Google Cloud Platform App Engine Instances?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

(Running Node.js on a Google App Engine Custom Runtime)

One of my service instances is currently not serving with the following error:

> Creating this instance is permanently failing. Try redeploying the version to fix it.

Ignoring for a moment my frustration over why an instance would sporadically stop working like that, it would have been nice to get notified of a failing instance.

Where do I setup health notifications for Google Cloud Platform App Engine Instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stackdriver Monitoring to monitor and also set alerts when something goes wrong:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Mete.